# wine : Depends: wine1.6

Tags: wine

I got an "wine : Depends: wine1.6" error that prevented me from installing anything.
`
This other software:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7C9J3.png)

I tried install wine1.6 but then show this error:
`cuong@cuong-Aspire-A715-72G:~$ sudo apt-get install wine1.6-i386 Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree        Reading state information... Done You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these. The following packages have unmet dependencies: wine : Depends: wine1.6 wine1.6-i386:i386 : Depends: wine1.6:any (= 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu4) Recommends: libp11-kit-gnome-keyring:i386 but it is not going to be installed Recommends: libpng12-0:i386 but it is not going to be installed Recommends: wine-gecko2.21:i386 but it is not installable Recommends: wine-mono0.0.8:i386 but it is not installable E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).` 
When I install `libp11-kit-gnome-keyring:i386` then show error  `wine : Depends: wine1.6`

Comment: Try 'apt --fix-broken install'

Comment: I tried but have this error:
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-9pIXjT/0-wine1.6-amd64_1%3a1.6.2-0ubuntu4_amd64.deb
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-9pIXjT/1-wine1.6-i386_1%3a1.6.2-0ubuntu4_i386.deb
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-9pIXjT/2-wine1.6_1%3a1.6.2-0ubuntu4_amd64.deb
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-9pIXjT/3-libpng12-0_1.2.50-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-9pIXjT/4-libpng12-0_1.2.50-1ubuntu2_i386.deb
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-9pIXjT/5-libp11-kit-gnome-keyring_3.10.1-1ubuntu4_i386.deb
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-9pIXjT/6-libp11-kit-gnome-keyring_3.10.1-1ubuntu4_a
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code